# Сохранение и загрузка переменной в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Понадобилось реализовать сохранение и загрузку переменной в юнити через сериализацию (При нажатии клавиши "S" она должна сохраняться, а при нажатии "L" загружаться).

Xml файл должен иметь такой вид:

```
<Scene1>
  <x>0</x>
</Scene1>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема именно в том, как работать с XML файлами, то приведу пример на C#.

Создаем класс Scene:

```
public class Scene
{
   public int x { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь можно создать скрипт для работы с XML.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class WorkWithXML
{
   public void Save(Scene sceneForSave)
   {
      XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scene));
      using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Scene.xml"))
      {
         serializer.Serialize(writer, sceneForSave); 
      } 
   }
   public Scene Load()
   {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Scene.xml");
      Scene loadedScene = (Scene)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      reader.Close();
      return loadedScene;
   }
}
```

В нужном месте кода вызывайте эти методы, создав экземпляр класса WorkWithXML или просто сделав эти методы static. Надеюсь, это подходящий ответ на ваш вопрос.